# 'float' object is not iterable within List Comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

I have two pandas series `plg` and `trd` which I've turned into lists and contain integers.
I want to create a correction calculation for `plg` and `trd` when `plg` is negative however I'm unsure of how to approach this with list comprehensions.

I've tried:

```
    plg = [ 1.3962634 ,  1.57079633, -0.52359878,  0.61086524,  0.83775804,
    0.17453293,  1.36135682,  1.43116999,  1.57079633,  1.57079633]
    trd = [2.0943951 , 2.86233997, 9.8087504 , 4.71238898, 5.41052068,
   1.13446401, 2.18166156, 2.12930169, 2.77507351, 2.91469985]

    Zero = def ZeroTwoPi(a):
    """
    Zero constrains azimuth to lie between 0 and 2*pi RADIANS.

    Returns azimuth b (from 0 to 2*pi) for input azimuth a.

    NOTE: Azimuths a and b are input/output in radians.
    """
    b = a;
    twopi = 2.0*np.pi
    x = [b + twopi if b < 0 else b - twopi if b>= twopi else b for b in a]
    return x

    plg_up = [-i if i < 0.0 else i for i in plg ]
    trd_up = [Zero(i - np.pi) if plg[index] < 0 else i for index,i in enumerate(trd)]
```

`plg` is returned correctly with the 3 element being returned to positive but `trd_up' can't seem to iterate through the Zero() function as it is a list. Would I just need to add in another enumerate() index for the list created by Zero()?

I can hotfix this by enclosing the argument of Zero() in a list :

```
trd_up = [Zero([i - np.pi]) if plg[index] < 0 else i for index,i in enumerate(trd)]
```

But this returns a list within a list:

```
[2.0943951023931953,
 2.8623399732707,
 [0.3839724354387517],
 4.71238898038469,
 5.410520681182422,
 1.1344640137963142,
 2.1816615649929116,
 2.129301687433082,
 2.775073510670984,
 2.9146998508305306]
```

Comment: That's because `[b < 0 for b in plg] is True` always evaluates to `False`

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you! I'm just not sure how I could now get (i - np.pi) to run for when b < 0 within plg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in other answers you can use `enumerate` for accessing element with same index from `plg`. Also, for your first list you can use `abs` built-in function.

```
plg_up = [abs(x) for x in plg]
trd_up = [x - np.pi if plg[i] < 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(trd)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to generate tuples of elements from `plg_up` and `trd_up`:

```
[(i,b) for (i,b) in zip(plg_up, trd_up)]
[(1.3962634, 2.0943951), (1.57079633, 2.86233997), (0.52359878, 6.658750399999999), (0.61086524, 4.71238898), (0.83775804, 5.41052068), (0.17453293, 1.13446401), (1.36135682, 2.18166156), (1.43116999, 2.12930169), (1.57079633, 2.77507351), (1.57079633, 2.91469985)]
```

This allows you to compare the respective value `b` from `trd_up` as you intended:

```
[i - np.pi if b < 0 else i for (i,b) in zip(plg_up, trd_up)]
[1.3962634, 1.57079633, 0.52359878, 0.61086524, 0.83775804, 0.17453293, 1.36135682, 1.43116999, 1.57079633, 1.57079633]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of `enumerate` to get an index for the element you are currently working on.  `enumerate` will let you get both the list element and its position in the list, which I called `index` below.  You can use `index` in the list comprehension to get the corresponding element in `plg`.

```py
trd_up = [i - np.pi if plg[index] < 0 else i for index, i in enumerate(trd)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simultaneously want to check for the coressponding element in the two lists for which you can use `enumerate` which will return you the element at the same position in the other list.
 `trd_up = [i - np.pi if plg[index]<0 else i for index,i in enumerate(trd)]`

Comment: How could I amend this code if i amend this (i-np.pi) is a list that is passed through a function that produces another list?

I have the following code format:

<pre class="prettyprint">
def ZeroTwoPi(a):
        b = a;
        twopi = 2.0*np.pi  
        x = [b + twopi if b < 0 else b - twopi if b>= twopi else b for b in a]
        return x


trd_up = [ZeroTwoPi([i - np.pi]) if plg[index]<0 else i for index,i in enumerate(trd)]</pre>

Which returns a list within a list whereas I'd like just one list.

Answer (score 0):

The up is right, the key point is you need to get the index.

If you do not want to use `enumerate`, just try `for` or `while` loop

For Example:

```py
for i in xrange(len(trd)):
    if plg[i]<0:
        trd_up[i]=trd[i]-np.pi
    else:
        trd_up[i]=trd[i]
```